# Spring JavaConfig equivalent of referring to beans by name

Tags: java, spring

In Spring XML config, I can use the ref="bean_name" syntax to refer to a bean by ID or name.

```
<bean id="petStore" class="org.springframework.samples.jpetstore.services.PetStoreServiceImpl">
    <property name="accountDao" ref="accountDao"/>
</bean>
```

Is there an equivalent way of achieving this in Java config, using the name attribute on the @Bean annotation? I've used the `@Named` annotation `(javax.inject.Named)` and have seen `@Qualifier` suggested elsewhere, but is a separate annotation really necessary if we already have a name attribute on the `@Bean` annotation?

Comment: show us your version of the JAva config.. lets see what is wrong with it

Comment: I haven't found a way of doing this, so it's more of a question of whether it is possible to do this.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it; ty

Answer (score 1):

`@Qualifier` is the correct thing to use here.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bean_name")
private Beantype var;
```

And declaring your component

```
@Component(value = "bean_name")
public class Beantype {...}
```

At least that works for me.